# Who listen 80 port in Windows 7 Home Basic

Tags: iis, windows-7-x64

I try use Apache on 80 port but Windows 7 says: "80 port in use". Which Windows service I must stop to release 80 port? 
P.S. Windows 7 Home Basic do not have IIS Managenent Console.

UPD: telnet open localhost 80

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Sun, 13 Apr 2014 12:16:05 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 326

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/str
ict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Verb</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request verb is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run as administrator cmd.exe and type

```
tasklist /M httpapi.dll
```

and take process list who use httpapi.dll

in my case it was Reporting Service too. These services need stop and set start up mode: manual.

P.S. Thank you for all.

Answer (score 2):

Use `netstat -bano` to see which program is bound to port 80.

Comment: TCP 0.0.0.0:80 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING 4 
Unable to get information about the owner

Comment: You can use `taskkill /PID XXX` to kill the process or use taskmanager.

Answer (score 2):

Maby you have running skype/teamviewer. they use port 80 to for extra sevices. otherwise navigate 127.0.0.1 with a browser and tell what you see.

Update: i see you have a Microsoft HTTPAPI/2.0 running:

Stop Service: `Web Deployment Agent Service (MsDepSvc)` and reboor system. that must make port 80 free also.